# floating point values comparison failure

Tags: c++, c

In C, if we execute the following code:

```
float a = 0.7;
if (a < 0.7)
{
    printf("Less");
}
else
{
    printf("no");
}
```

The code above code prints "Less".

But if we execute the following code:

```
float a = 1.7;
if (a < 1.7)
{
    printf("Less");
}
else
{
    printf("no");
}
```

It prints "no".

What's the reason for that? How does the float datatype work?

Comment: you might want to lookup "floating point rounding errors" - there are huge articles about those issues :-)

Comment: A must read - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: [As you can see here](https://ideone.com/e8N7pn), it prints less with C++11 as well. Refer to Luchian's links as to why.

Comment: if you really want to compare floating literals, add F after it like 23.6F.

Comment: like= 100/3 = 33.3333...... similarly when you convert `0.7` in binary you will get a infinite(or long) sequence of `0`,`1` that is the reason four byte `float` `.7f`!= eight byte `double` `0.7`.Just remember unsuffixed floating-point literals are double,  and rounding means that even small literals can take on different values when rounded to float and double.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that `a` is a `float`, but `0.7` is a `double`. The values assigned into `a` are converted from `double` to `float`, which loses precision. When you compare `a` back to the `double`, `a` is widened to a `double`, but the precision is already lost, and they may no longer be equal.

If you change `0.7` and `1.7` to `0.7f` and `1.7f` then they will be converted to `float` literals and will reliably compare equal to `a` in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

The `float` datatype works with approximate values. Every numeric data type in C/C++ uses a finite, fixed amount of bytes to store values. `float` stores values in exponential format in such a way that if you pass a value in another format to it, the value will be rounded... And then, if you look at enough digits past the decimal separator you are sure to see non-zero values. And `1.7`, as Peter Alexander said in his answer, is not a "pure" float value.

A further, detailed explanation of the motives behind such a design might be too long for an asnwer here - but you may read more about that if you google for it. One of the commenters, Luchian, left a good link there: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html